# Internationalize the title of application

Tags: android, flutter

For Android.

There is the name of application here.

in my `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
   <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="MyAppName"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

However I want to internationalize, application name
so make the `strings.xml` for each langs

`android/app/src/main/res/value-en/strings.xml`

`android/app/src/main/res/value-ja/strings.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Localized App</string>
</resources>
```

However application name is not changed.

I am using flutter to make application, so it should be the question of flutter or android??

Or is there any other smart way to change the name of application name??

Comment: Did you change the attribute too? `android:label="@string/app_name"` Also note that the res directories are `values-xx` not `value-xx`

Comment: Thanks a lot !! it is solved!